# Comparison of different topologies on the ordered square.

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I have a problem regarding the question

> Let $I=[0,1]$.Show by sketching a proof, that the dictionary order topology
> on the set $I × I $ is strictly finer than the product topology on the set $I × I.$

I feel this is wrong because  $(1/2,1)$ is in $I^2$ and there are open set in product topology which contain it and there is no open set in dictionary order completely inside it.similary for otherway.

And I found an answer [Comparison of different topologies on the ordered square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1497777/743801). Can anyone please tell me am I misunderstanding something?

Given question is said to show that these two are comparable,i m tired of trying this that is why i post this.

Comment: When you claim that “$(1/2,1)$ is in $I^2$”, are you claiming that $(1/2,1)$ is an *element* of $I^2$, or are you claiming that it is a *subset* of $I^2$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos as an element

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos is this problem correct?

Comment: You claim that there is no open set in the product topology to which $(1/2,1)$ belongs. That's not true. For instance $(1/2,1)\in I^2$, and $I^2$ *is* an open set with respect to the product topology.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I am saying that there are open set $  u $ contain that point in product topology but there is no open set $v$ contain that point in orderd topology such that $(1/2,1)) \in v \subset u$. By comparing basis.

Comment: Sure. My bad. But what I wrote is correct for the dictionary order topology: there is an open set from that topology to which $(1/2,1)$ belongs, namely $I^2$ itself.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Got it. From what i am saying can i claim that these are not finer?

Comment: What does that mean? That none of the topologies is finer than the other one?